# Free PHP script to detect mobile devices

Tags: php, mobile, user-agent

Simple question, what are some good free mobile device detection scripts that people have used and find work the best? I need to redirect mobile users to a mobile version of our site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WURFL si deemed to be the best outhere : http://sourceforge.net/projects/wurfl/files/WURFL/

NB : beware the license change for latest version, here is a [direct link to v2.2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wurfl/files/WURFL/2.2/)

Answer (score 4):

I use this in my projects:

```
function checkMobile()  {
    if (preg_match("/Mobile|Android|BlackBerry|iPhone|Windows Phone/", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
        header(Location: MOBILE SITE);
    }
}
```

I then call this function in the head of my html document like this:

```
<?php checkMobile() ?>
```

Comment: You've got an extra opening bracket at the end of the if statement.
You can either remove the extra opening bracket after the if, or add another closing bracket.

Comment: Oh, also this does work well enough for me but I removed "Android" from the list since that would catch android tablets as well.

Answer (score 2):

http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/ This should help you out.